# Jpa2.0 Hibernate how to handle Oracle VARRAY type

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, varray

I have field VARRAY of FLOAT. And I try to load this field in JAVA with JPA2.0/hiberhate. I found only that TopLink provider support VARRAY, but no information what should I do for Hibernate provider. Normalisation of tables it is not my way... Because I have a lot of items.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Go through JPA 2.0 specification and try to find any section talking about data types. I doubt you will find anything useful. AFAIK ver. 2.1 introduced a way how to handle custom data types. Most of the databases support only scalar data types you should use only NUMBERs, STRINGs and DATEs if you insists on using something which promises to be db vendor independent.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to switch to JPA 2.1? There is a [`TypeConverter`](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to.html)

Comment: Thanks for answers, It is a difficult qustion, for now I can't use JPA 2.1...